# Compute $\lim_{n\to1}(n^5-(n^3-1)^{-1})$

Tags: limits

Compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to 1}\left(n^5 - \cfrac1{n^3 - 1}\right)$. It's undefined, but how do I show it?

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{ n\to 1}\frac{n^5-1}{n^3-1}=\lim_{ n\to 1}\frac{(n-1)(n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1)}{(n-1)(n^2+n+1)}=\lim_{ n\to 1 }\frac{(n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1)}{(n^2+n+1)}$$ as $n\to1\implies n\ne 1,n-1\ne 0$

$$\lim_{ n\to 1}\frac{n^5-1}{n^3-1}=\frac5 3$$, so the limit does exist at $x=1$.

---

For the modified case,

$\lim_{n \to 1}\left(n^5 - \cfrac1{n^3 - 1}\right)=\lim_{n \to 1}\left(\cfrac{n^8-n^5 - 1}{n^3-1}\right)$

$\lim_{n \to 1^+}\left(n^5 - \cfrac1{n^3 - 1}\right)=-\infty$

$\lim_{n \to 1^-}\left(n^5 - \cfrac1{n^3 - 1}\right)=\infty$

Comment: For $n\to 1$, yes, but $n\to\infty$ was the question.

Comment: @Berci, look at the original question that was edited by Hagen

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\frac{n^5-1}{n^3-1}=n^2\cdot\frac{1-n^{-5}}{1-n^{-3}}$.

Comment: N tends to 1 pls.(not infinity).

Comment: Then what's with $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}$ in OP's question?